# Monadic bind with Cmd

Tags: monads, elm

I have a function

```
convertMsg : Msg1 -> List Msg2
```

where `Msg1` and `Msg2` are certain message types.  And I would like to turn this into a function:

```
convertCmd : Cmd Msg1 -> Cmd Msg2
```

Which would for every message in the batch replace it with some messages possibly none or more than 1.

As a Haskell programmer at heart I immediately reach for a monadic bind (`(>>=)` in Haskell and `andThen` in the Elm parlance), a function with the type:

```
bind : (a -> Cmd b) -> Cmd a -> Cmd b
```

I can easily change my `convertMsg` to be the following:

```
convertMsg : msg1 -> Cmd Msg2
```

At which point it would be just perfect for the `bind`.

But looking in [Platform.Cmd](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#Cmd), there isn't such a function I can find.  There's a `map` which is similar, but `convertMsg` can't really be `convertMsg : Msg1 -> Msg2` since it doesn't always give back exactly one message.

Is there a way to achieve this?  Is there some limitation to the `Cmd` type that would prevent this sort of thing?

Answer (score 7):

### **What you're trying to do to messages, how you might, and whether it's a good plan**

I promise I'll try to answer what I think you're trying to do, but first I think there's a more important thing...

You're perhaps assuming that `Cmd` is analogous to `IO` from Haskell, but `Cmd` is asynchronous and isn't designed to chain actions. Your `update` is what glues consequences to outputs:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model,Cmd Msg)
```

At the end of your `update`, you can issue a `Cmd Msg` to ask elm to do something externally, usually passing it a constructor with which it can wrap its output. This output comes back to your `update` function.

What you *don't* do is chain `Cmd`s together as you would in a monad. There's no `bind` for `Cmd`, or to put it another way, the only `bind` for `Cmd` is your `update` function!

Now I suppose that if you wanted to catch a `MyComplexMsg : Msg` and turn it into `[SimpleMsg1,SimpleMsg2]`, you could pattern match for it in your `update` function, leave the model unchanged and issue a new `Cmd Msg`, but what command would you be running the second time?

You could certainly take a pure `Msg -> List Msg` function and use `Cmd.map` to apply it, or apply it manually in the pattern match at the beginning of `update`, like

```
update msg model = case msg of
    MyComplexMsg -> myHandler [SimpleMsg1,SimpleMsg2]
    ...
```

or even go full state monad style with

```
update msg model0 = case msg of
    MyComplexMsg -> 
        let 
            (model1,cmd1) = update SimpleMsg1 model0
            (model2,cmd2) = update SimpleMsg2 model1
        in
            (model2,Cmd.batch [cmd1,cmd2])
```

to try to emulate monadic bind, but I don't know why you might ever want this, and a lot of advice in the elm literature and community is that if you're calling update from update you're probably doing it wrong. Make a separate single-purpose helper function for that stuff instead of re-running your entire program logic twice!

### **Let go of your need to have a monad**

I suspect that what's going wrong is that you're not letting go of a monadic control flow mentality. `update` is where it's at. `update` is where you make things happen. User input and asynchronous messages are your drivers, not sequencing. `Cmd` is just for communicating externally. You don't plumb the results back in, the elm architecture does that for you. Just handle the result of your `Cmd` (which will arrive as a message) as a branch in your `update` and it'll all progress nicely, and if the user presses some button of their own choice without you making it happen, so be it. You can handle that too.

I worry that you're trying to write a monad transformer stack in elm, which is a bit like trying to write an object oriented programming library in haskell. Haskell doesn't do object oriented programming, and the sooner folks drop the OO thinking and let go of their need to bundle data and functions together, the sooner they're writing good haskell code. Elm doesn't do typeclasses, it does model/view/update, and does it extraordinarily well. Let go of your need to find and use a monad to control the flow of your program, and instead respond to what messages you're given. Make a `Msg` for something you want to happen, provide a way to trigger it appropriately in your `view` and then handle it in your `update`.

### **When should one message become three messages?**

If one of your messages is really three messages, why isn't it three messages already? If it's just that in response to that particular message, you just need to do three things to your model and issue five commands, why not just have **one** message and get `update` to do those three things to your model using pure code and issue the five commands in a batch?

If you need to log the successful login, *then* get the user's photo, *then* query the database for their recent activity, *then* display it all, then I disagree about the immediateness, and they're all asynchronous. You can issue commands to do each of those things in a batch, and when the responses come back you will need to separately deal with each - update your model with the image when it arrives, with the list of recent activity when it arrives. Once your model is in the state that the picture and the recent activity are both there you can change the view, but why not show each as soon as they're there?

Using monads sometimes trains us to think sequentially when we're doing effects programming when we needn't, but now, finally, I'll address what to do when there is a compelling need to sequence commands.

### **Genuinely necessary sequential commands**

Perhaps there really is something sequential that you need. Maybe you have to query some data store for something before you send some request elsewhere. You still don't use a bind, you just use your `update`:

```
update msg model = case msg of

    StartsMultiStageProcess userID -> 
        ({model|multiStageProcessStatus = RequestedData}
        , getDataPart1 userID PartOneReceived )

    PartOneReceived userData -> 
        ({model|multiStageProcessStatus = Fired}
        , fireRockets userData.nemesis.location RocketResult)

    RocketResult r -> if model.multiStageProcessStatus == Fire then 
      case r of
        Ok UtterlyDestroyed -> 
            ....
        Ok DamagedBeyondUse ->
            ....
        Err disappointment -> 
            ....
      ...
```

A handy point is that if your model doesn't have the required data, it automatically won't show the missing data in the view (sum types for the win), and you can store whatever state your multistage process is in in the model.

You might prefer to put all of those messages into a new type so it becomes indented once further in the handler and won't ever be mixed with other ones in the order, like

```
    MSPmsg msg -> case msg of
        Started userId ->
            ... 
        GotPartOne userData ->
```

but much more likely use a helper function like `MSPmsg msg -> updateMultiStageProcess`.

### **Concluding advice**

Maybe there's some great use case for delving into messages and commands and editing them that you haven't made explicit, but `Cmd` is opaque and all you can do is issue them and handle the resulting messages, so I'm sceptical but definitely interested.

Also in giving you `update` to write, it's almost like they've given you the app-specific `bind` to write (but it's *not* a functor and you absolutely *do* look at the data), so they've given you the keys to the Tesla. It takes a bit of getting used to but you're *really* going to like what happens at the traffic lights. Don't attempt to dismantle the door hinges until you've learned to drive it.

## Edit: **Your specific use case: inter-page communication**

It turns out in chat that you're trying to get messages from one page to be usable in other pages or the overall update - sometimes one page needs to tell the app to change page and tell the new page to start an animation. I might have skipped all the advice above if I'd known that initially, but I think it's good advice for anyone coming from Haskell and I'm leaving it in!

#### Multiple messages

I still think it's important to accept that sometimes a single message needs to cover multiple actions, and you sort that out in your `update` function rather than try to create multiple messages in response to a single user action.

Lots of elm folks give the advice that your messages, rather than describing something to do like `AddProduct` they should describe something that happened in the past, partly because that's how messages come to you in your `update` so your mental model of what the elm runtime is doing is accurate, and partly because you're less likely to want to make two messages and do weird message translations when you ought to make one message.

> **Do multiple things in your `ClickedViewOffers` branch of `update` rather than try to make both a `SwitchToOffersPage` and a
> `AnimatePickOfTheDay` message.**

I'd like to point out that your idea to convert your messages and filter them somehow within the messages type is doing it in the wrong place. Filtering so that your Home page doesn't get all the messages for your Login page is something you have to do in `update` anyway - don't try to filter them while you're making or passing the messages. `update` is where it's at for deciding what to do in response to user input. Messages are for describing user input.

#### OK, but how do you get messages to cross the barriers between pages?!

There are a few ways to achieve this and it might be worth looking into different ways of making a Single Page Application (SPA) in Elm. I found [this article](https://rchavesferna.medium.com/child-parent-communication-in-elm-outmsg-vs-translator-vs-nomap-patterns-f51b2a25ecb1) by Rogério Chaves on Medium quite enlightening on the topic of various ways of organising messages from child page to parent app. He's done the TodoMVC app all the different ways in [this repo](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/structured-elm-todomvc) A stack overflow post is better if it inlines ideas, so here we go:

1. **Common Msg type across all pages**

This can work by having a separate module for your message types which all your modules import. Messages look like `ProductsMsg (UserCreatedNewProduct productRecord)`, as they might well do anyway, but because all the message types are global you can call another page's methods.

2. **Individual pages also return an OutMsg from their update function**

Use better names than these (eg `Login.Msg` rather than `LoginMsg`), but...

```
loginPageUpdate : LoginMsg -> LoginModel -> (LoginModel,Cmd LoginMsg,OutMsgFromLogin)
```

```
update : GlobalMsg -> GlobalModel -> (GlobalModel,Cmd GlobalMsg)
update msg model = case msg of
   LoginMsg loginMsg ->
        let (newLoginModel,cmd,outMsgFromLogin) = loginPageUpdate loginMsg model.loginModel 
        in
           ...
```

(You'd need `NoOp :: OutMsgFromLogin` or use `Maybe OutMsgFromLogin` there. I'm not a fan of `NoOp`. It's terribly tempting to use it for unimplemented features, and it's the king of all divorced-from-user-intentions messages that doesn't explain why you ought to do nothing or how you came to write something where you generated a purposeless message. I think it's a code smell that there's a better way of writing something.)

3. **Have a record of messages that you later use to translate your page's `Msg`s messages into global messages.**

(Again, use better domain-specific names, I'm trying to convey usage in my names.)

```
type LoginMessagesRecord globalMsg = 
   { internalLoginMsgTag : LoginMsg -> globalMsg 
   , loginSucceeded : User -> globalMsg
   , loginFailed : globalMsg
   , newUserSuccessfullyRegistered : User -> globalMsg
   }
```

and in your main, you would specify these:

```
loginMessages : LoginMessagesRecord GlobalMsg
loginMessages = 
   { internalLoginMsgTag = LocalLoginMsg
   , loginSucceeded = LoginSucceeded
   , loginFailed = LoginFailed
   , newUserSuccessfullyRegistered = NewUserSuccessfullyRegistered
   }
```

You can either parameterise functions in your Login code with those so they all consume a LoginMessagesRecord and produce a `msg`, or you can use a genuinely local message type and write a translation helper in your Login module:

```
type HereOrThere here there = Here here | There there
type LocalLoginMessage = EditedUserName String | EditedPassword String | ....
type MessageForElsewhere = LoggedIn User | DidNotLogIn | MadeNewAccount User
type alias LoginMsg = HereOrThere LocalLoginMessage MessageForElsewhere

loginMsgTranslator : LoginMessagesRecord msg -> LoginMsg -> msg
loginMsgTranslator 
   { internalLoginMsgTag
   , loginSucceeded 
   , loginFailed 
   , newUserSuccessfullyRegistered 
   }
   loginMsg = case loginMsg of
       Here msg -> internalLoginMsgTag msg
       There msg -> case msg of
            LoggedIn user -> loginSucceeded user
            DidNotLogIn -> loginFailed 
            MadeNewAccount user -> newUserSuccessfullyRegistered user
```

and then you can use `Html.map loginMsgTranslator loginView` in your global view, or `Element.map loginMsgTranslator loginView` if you're using the utterly brilliant html&css-free way to write elm apps, [elm-ui](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/elm-ui/latest/).

## Summary / takeaway

- Have a single message describing a user intention and use update to handle all the consequences.
- Don't edit the messages, respond appropriately in the update
- The user is in control. The runtime is in control. You're not in control. Don't generate messages yourself, just respond to them. If you're generating messages rather than the user or the runtime, you're using elm in a weird way that'll be hard.
- Your program logic largely resides in update. It doesn't reside in message. Don't try to make things happen in message, just describe what the user did or what the system did in the message.
- Use case statements and descriptive tags in message types to help choose which update helper function to run. It can often help to use union types to describe how local a message is. Sometimes you use a local updating function, sometimes a global one.

You might want to also read [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/65s0g4/resources_regarding_scaling_elm_apps/) about scaling elm apps that Rogério Chaves references.

Comment: I was not thinking of `Cmd` as analogous to `IO`, because it kind of obviously is not.  As is hinted in my opening sentence, the most analogous monad here is `List`.  I'm not trying to chain anything, nor do I have anything remotely representing a proper monad stack.  What I want to do translate messages used by one part of the application to another.  It's really quite close to what `Cmd.map` does already except with the added bit that some messages are not translated and should be dropped.

Comment: I wrote much more in my answer in an update. You might be interested in the **Genuinely necessary sequential commands** section.

Comment: You can definitely write a pure function that replaces a `Msg` with `List OtherMsg` and `Cmd.map` that, but I still think you're trying to do something in an unnecessary way, but it's very hard to tell unless you're prepared to share the sort of thing you're attempting. It feels like someone new to haskell is asking to make a list containing arbitrary types. They probably don't need to but you can't suggest an alternative if they present their problem as how to mix different data types in a list. You talk about sum types but it turns out they didn't need to put anything in a list at all.

Comment: Perhaps you could let me know what you were trying to achieve rather than how you were trying to achieve it, or at least something analogous?

Comment: Actually, perhaps the **When should one message be three things?** section is more what I want to say under the circumstances. Why doesn't one part of your code just call the other in its message handler or as part of it's function body? Everything's a function, you can just use it. What do you mean by "part" of your application? A different page, a different mode, a different module?

Comment: In short I have several different pages separated each with their own update, model, view etc. the main application then is just the necessary glue to take the user between the pages of the application.  Usually when messages do not move between pages for somewhat obvious reasons.  However some animations do need to jump between pages, i.e. an animation can be triggered on one page to be animated on another page.  So in my top level I want to say "When you are switching between pages, here's how you translate messages from the old page".  cont...

Comment: `Cmd.map` does just that, *except* every message in needs to correspond to exactly 1 message out, which isn't exactly how things work for me.

Comment: Right, so like when I've clicked the ShowMeGreatOffers button on the preferences page and then when I go to a product page the special offers sidebar wobbles a little and glows pleasingly, or like when I've clicked the ShowMeGreatOffers button it goes straight to the products page and wobbles the sidebar etc? Could you do that like `let newProductInfo = { model.productInfo | mode=HighlightOffers } in  ( { model | page=Products, productInfo=newProductInfo}, Cmd.none)` and then issue the animating command based on whether `mode==HighlightOffers` in whatever update brings you to see products?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243703/discussion-between-wheat-wizard-and-andrewc).

Comment: @WheatWizard I got around to writing a much more use-case-specific response in what is now the second half of my answer. Hopefully despite the delay it's still of some use to you. I apologise for not first asking _why_ you wanted to do what you wanted to do; until I found that out, my advice was rather general and in some cases was clearly frustrating you because I missed the point or guessed incorrectly where you were coming from. Hope the project goes well and sorry for being too scatter-gun initially.